# libVLC function media_player_new() throws Segmentation Fault

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, vlc, libvlc

media_player_new() throws segmentation fault.

```
import vlc
ins=vlc.Instance()
player=ins.media_player_new()
```

Here is where it crashes:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libvlc.dylib   0x000000010059aa78 libvlc_media_player_new + 24
```

libvlc.dylib is in the place where script is looking: /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib

vlc.py can be found here: git://git.videolan.org/vlc/bindings/python.git

Any ideas why or how to debug?

Comment: I have this problem too. Most of the times segfaults I had where because I had 2 different archs, but it seems the dylib is universal.

Answer (score 2):

Launch Python in 32 bit modes by running `export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes` This is not an ideal solution, but it works for me.

Applying these patches will fix the issue for real: http://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/4686