# How do I avoid libVLC throwing segmentation fault when calling self.stop()

Tags: python, youtube, wxpython, segmentation-fault, libvlc

I'm using libVLC with wxPython to stream videos from YouTube. Playing and pausing the videos works well but when I try to stop the video using self.player.stop(), the program seg faults. I also get this problem when using self.Media.release(). I tried running Python in 32 bit mode but that didn't help.

There are two messages that I receive when this happens. Sometimes the stack reads "Segmentation fault: 11" and other times it read "Bus error: 10"

The seg fault also occurs when stopping local videos as well.

How do I fix this so that I can stop videos?

By the way, I read through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901669/libvlc-function-media-player-new-throws-segmentation-fault) but that didn't help. media_player_new() works fine for me.

Comment: A faulty Python code shouldn't cause a segfault. This means it's a bug in either the libVLC or Python bindings to it.